# Resources/books/articles about estimation of |f(z)|

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am new to complex analysis and I want to explore the following:
For complex valued  bounded functions $f (z)$ in a domain, I would like to know how we estimate the modulus values in a given domain, especially when $ f $ is a polynomial. I would be highly obliged if someone could kindly refer me to the relevant books/articles/papers

Comment: Functions of One Complex Variable I by John B. conway Second edition Springer publications